# Storyboards + generics = inline initializers not called?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, interface-builder

I'm looking for an explanation of why the following prints `false` when run on iOS. The view controller is instantiated from a dead-simple Storyboard which just contains a single table view.

I'm using the preloading trick suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658528/1919412 to allow Interface Builder to find the `MyTableViewController` class. I'm sure that has something to do with the problem, but I'd like to better understand what's going on.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    // If we don't create this dummy instance before our real view controller gets loaded from storyboard, we get this error:
    //  "Unknown class _TtC21ViewControllerInitBug21MyTableViewController in Interface Builder file."
    // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658528/1919412
    let foo = MyTableViewController()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class Foo<T>:UITableViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(style:.Plain)
    }
}

class MyTableViewController:Foo<String> {
    private var foo = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(self.foo)
    }
}
```

Comment: On further reflection, I don't understand why this even compiles! Shouldn't the compiler complain that I haven't implemented `init?(coder:NSCoder)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic controller in swift 2.0 using storyboards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836343/generic-controller-in-swift-2-0-using-storyboards)

Comment: No, that is not the same question. I even referenced that exact question in mine, specifically to prevent people from jumping to that conclusion.