# Xcode 7 Swift 2 impossible to instantiate UIViewController subclass of generic UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

I have a generic class:

```
class PaginatedTableViewController
  <GenericElement, Source: PaginationDataSource 
     where Source.PaginatedGenericElement == GenericElement>:
  UITableViewController
```

and another that I try to instantiate from storyboard:

```
class CandidatesTableViewController: 
   PaginatedTableViewController<Match, MatchPaginationDataSource>
```

I can't find `CandidatesTableViewController` in the storyboard Custom Class dropdown menu. If I force it then cast my controller in code, app crashes at runtime complaining my controller (that should be a CandidatesTableViewController instance) is in fact a UITableViewController instance.

> Unknown class _TtC21MyProjectName29CandidatesTableViewController in
>   Interface Builder file.
>   Could not cast value of type
>   'UITableViewController' (0x1040917f8) to
>   'MyProjectName.CandidatesTableViewController' (0x1013a9890).

In my project this controller is embedded in another one that's why I cast it :

```
tableViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! CandidatesTableViewController)
```

Does any one knows how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, generic Swift classes are not visible to Objective-C code and also are not supported in Interface Builder (in storyboards and xibs). I find these two points closely related.

As a solution I would suggest you to use aggregation: do not make you view controller generic, but extract some logic to another (generic) class and use it inside your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you manually load your generic VC into Objective-C runtime manually via the `load()` method i.e. call. `PaginatedTableViewController.load()`  in your app delegate's init method. Idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43896830/671580