# Check if two objects implement a Swift protocol and its associated type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I have a Swift 3 project where I'm declaring a protocol with an associated type like this:

```
protocol ViewModelContainer {
    associatedtype ViewModelType
    var viewModel: ViewModelType! { get set }
}
```

And I want to check if two objects implement `ViewModelContainer` and it's associated type `ViewModelType` to make the assignment in a 'generic' way.

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
if let container = container as? ViewModelContainer, let model = model as? container.ViewModelType {
    container.viewModel = model
}
```

But I can't cast `container` to `ViewModelContainer`:

> Protocol 'ViewModelContainer' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

---

My current workaround is to fall back to specific classes and their associated types directly, but it leaves my code very verbose and error prone:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? MediaPlaySelectionViewController, let vm = sender as? MediaPlaySelectionViewModel {
        vc.viewModel = vm
    }
    if let vc = segue.destination as? SearchResultsViewController, let vm = sender as? SearchResultsViewModel {
        vc.viewModel = vm
    }
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ReviewDetailsViewController, let vm = sender as? ReviewDetailsViewModel {
        vc.viewModel = vm
    }
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ReviewComposerViewController, let vm = sender as? ReviewComposerViewModel {
        vc.viewModel = vm
    }
}
```

I tried using generic `UIViewController`s, but got stuck because [Objective-C doesn't recognize generic Swift classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534854/xcode-7-swift-2-impossible-to-instantiate-uiviewcontroller-subclass-of-generic-u) and therefore can't be used in Storyboard.

Comment: This is really stupid... but if you make an empty protocol, and then make all types conforming to `ViewModelContainer` conform to that protocol, then you check for conformance to that protocol without bumping up against this issue.

Comment: I guess the real question is why isn't `container` statically typed as a type that conforms to `ViewModelContainer`? You may well be looking for a type eraser.

Comment: Why not make the `ViewModelType` as a protocol?

Comment: @Hamish UIKit hates generics and I'm being forced to use `Any` at some point to workaround it

Comment: @dichen I already have a `ViewModel` protocol. But it doesn't help here because each container must contain its specific view model class.

Comment: @redent84 It would probably help if you gave us a concrete example of the problem you're facing.

Comment: @redent84, agree with above, give more detail, that help others to understand your goal.

Comment: @Hamish Updated with real code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was trickier than I expected (so I deleted my previous post to avoid confusion) but I believe this should work for you:

```
 protocol ViewModelContainerVC 
 {
   mutating func setModel(_ :Any)
 }

 protocol ViewModelContainer:class,ViewModelContainerVC 
 {
     associatedtype ViewModelType
     var viewModel: ViewModelType! { get set }
 }

 extension ViewModelContainer
 {
    mutating func setModel(_ model:Any)
    { if model is ViewModelType { viewModel = model as! ViewModelType } }
 }
```

You can then use the ViewModelContainerVC for type casting and assignment:

```
 if let container = container as? ViewModelContainerVC 
 { 
   container.setModel(model)
 }
```

[EDIT] for future reference, here's the same thing with a Bool return for type compatibility:

```
 protocol ViewModelContainerVC 
 {
   @discardableResult mutating func setModel(_ :Any) -> Bool
 }

 extension ViewModelContainer
 {
    @discardableResult mutating func setModel(_ model:Any) -> Bool
    { 
       if let validModel = model as? ViewModelType 
       { viewModel = validModel; return true }
       return false 
    }
 }
```

Which will allow a combined condition :

```
 if var container = container as? ViewModelContainerVC,
    container.setModel(model) 
 { ... }
```

Comment: It's a good workaround. But why use `is` and `as!` instead of `if let` or `as?` directly?

Comment: No particular reason, I just felt it better conveyed the intent.

Comment: This seems very un-swifty: The `setModel` method silently fails when called with the wrong type but the compiler does not help. You can call it on any `ViewModelContainer` with an argument of any type.

Comment: You could always add another method in the protocols to validate the type of the model . e.g. func matchesModel(model) -> Bool  or make the setModel function return a Bool result itself.

Comment: I'm finally using this solution returning `true` if the model is valid. I like that neither the view model or the controller is polluted and all the boilerplate is kept in an extension method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea of changing the `associatedtype ViewModelType` to a protocol.

```
protocol ViewModelProtocol {
}

protocol ViewModelContainer {

    var viewModel: ViewModelProtocol? { get set }
}

class MediaPlaySelectionViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {

    var title: String?
    func play() {
        print("playing")
    }
}

class SearchResultsViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {

    var results: [String]?
}

class MediaPlaySelectionViewController: UIViewController, ViewModelContainer {

    var viewModel: ViewModelProtocol?

    // So the view itself know which kind of vm it wants.
    var myViewModel: MediaPlaySelectionViewModel? {
        return viewModel as? MediaPlaySelectionViewModel
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print(myViewModel?.title ?? "Undefined")
    }
}

class SearchResultsViewController: UIViewController, ViewModelContainer {

    var viewModel: ViewModelProtocol?

    // So the view itself know which kind of vm it wants.
    var myViewModel: SearchResultsViewModel? {
        return viewModel as? SearchResultsViewModel
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print(myViewModel?.results?.joined(separator: ", ") ?? "No Result")
    }
}

class MenuViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        // NOTE: Swift doesn't allow me to use 'let' here
        if var container = segue.destination as? ViewModelContainer, let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, let vm = viewModel(for: cell) {
            container.viewModel = vm
        }
    }

    // NOTE: One difficulty here, how could you decide which ViewModel to prepare?  I guess you need a Factory.
    func viewModel(for cell: UITableViewCell) -> ViewModelProtocol! {

        if let index = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {

            if index.item == 0 {

                let vm = MediaPlaySelectionViewModel()
                vm.title = "My Video"

                return vm
            }
            else if index.item == 1 {

                let vm = SearchResultsViewModel()
                vm.results = ["Apple", "Banana"]

                return vm
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I prefer a little verbosity on the `prepare` rather than much more verbosity on the view model **and** losing type safety