# Swift how to create a generic MVP like UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, generics, mvp

I want to remove repetitive code so I would like to create a simple MVP base view controller that will tie together a model, view and presenter types and automatically connect them e.g.:

```
class BaseMvpViewController<M: MvpModel, V: MvpView, P: MvpPresenter>: UIViewController {
```

Where my model and view are empty protocols:

```
protocol MvpModel {}
protocol MvpView: class {} // class is needed for weak property
```

and presenter looks like this:

```
protocol MvpPresenter {
    associatedtype View: MvpView
    weak var view: View? { get set }
    func onAttach(view: View)
    func onDetach(view: View)
}
```

This is my whole `BaseMvpViewController`:

```
class BaseMvpViewController<M: MvpModel, V, P: MvpPresenter>: UIViewController, MvpView {
    typealias View = V
    var model: M? = nil
    var presenter: P!

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    deinit {
        presenter.onDetach(view: self as! View)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        createPresenter()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter.onAttach(view: self as! View)
    }

    func createPresenter() {
        guard presenter != nil else {
            preconditionFailure("Presenter was not created or it was not assigned into the `presenter` property!")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `V` must be without the protocol i.e. cannot be `V: MvpView`. Otherwise specific implementation of a VC must have a class/struct and not just a protocol for the `MvpView`. All my views are just protocols and my VCs will implement them e.g.

```
class MyViewController: BaseMvpViewController<MyModel, MyView, MyPresenter>, MyView
```

Now the compiler complains in the `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` methods that "argument type 'V' does not conform to expected type 'MvpView'"

So I tried an extension:

```
extension BaseMvpViewController where V: MvpView {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        presenter.onAttach(view: self as! View)
    }
}
```

yet another compiler error: "cannot invoke 'onAttach' with an argument list of type '(view: V)'". There is another small compilation error "Members of constrained extensions cannot be declared @objc" where I `override func viewDidLoad()` in the extension. This can be fixed by my own method and calling that one from `viewDidLoad` in the custom class. Any idea how to achieve what I want?

This is a similar/same issue like [Using some protocol as a concrete type conforming to another protocol is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503602) but maybe something has been improved in the Swift world since then. Or did I really hit a hard limit in the current Swift's capabilities?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534854/xcode-7-swift-2-impossible-to-instantiate-uiviewcontroller-subclass-of-generic-u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In have finally found a solution, the problem was in casting `self as! View`, it must be `self as! P.View`. And there cannot be a base protocol for view because protocols do not conform to themselves in Swift. Here is my complete code:

```
protocol MvpPresenter {
    associatedtype View
    var view: View? { get set }
    var isAttached: Bool { get }

    func onAttach(view: View)
    func onDetach(view: View)
}

/// Default implementation for the `isAttached()` method just checks if the `view` is non nil.
extension MvpPresenter {
    var isAttached: Bool { return view != nil }
}

class BaseMvpViewController<M, V, P: MvpPresenter>: UIViewController {
    typealias View = V
    var viewModel: M? = nil
    private(set) var presenter: P!

    //MARK: - Initializers

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override public init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }

    deinit {
        presenter.onDetach(view: self as! P.View)
    }

    //MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter = createPresenter()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard let view = self as? P.View else {
            preconditionFailure("MVP ViewController must implement the view protocol `\(View.self)`!")
        }

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (!presenter.isAttached) {
            presenter.onAttach(view: view)
        }
    }

    //MARK: - MVP

    /// Override and return a presenter in a subclass.
    func createPresenter() -> P {
        preconditionFailure("MVP method `createPresenter()` must be override in a subclass and do not call `super.createPresenter()`!")
    }
}
```

And a sample VC:

```
class MyGenericViewController: BaseMvpViewController<MyModel, MyView, MyPresenter>, MyView {
    ...
    override func createPresenter() -> MainPresenter {
        return MyPresenter()
    }
    ...
}
```

This VC will automatically have a `viewModel` property of type `MyModel` (could be anything e.g. struct, class, enum, etc), property `presenter` of type `MyPresenter` and this presenter will be automatically attached between `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`. One method must be overridden, the `createPresenter()` where you must create and return a presenter. This is called before the custom VC's `viewDidLoad` method. Presenter is detached in the `deinit`.

The last problem is that generic view controllers cannot be used in interface builder (IB), because IB talks to code via Objective-C runtime and that does not know true generics, thus does not see our generic VC. The app crashes when instantiating a generic VC from a storyboard/xib. There is a trick though that fixes this. Just load the generic VC manually into the Objective-C runtime before any instantiation from storyboard/xib. Good is in `AppDelegate`'s `init` method:

```
init() {
    ...
    MyGenericViewController.load()
    ...
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
I have found the loading of generic VC into Objective-C runtime in this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43896830/671580

**EDIT 2:**
Sample presenter class. The mandatory things is the `typealias`, the `weak var view: View?` and the `onAttach` & `onDetach` methods. Minimum implementation of the attach/detach methods is also provided.

```
class SamplePresenter: MvpPresenter {
    // These two are needed!
    typealias View = SampleView
    weak var view: View?

    private let object: SomeObject
    private let dao: SomeDao

    //MARK: - Initializers

    /// Sample init method which accepts some parameters.
    init(someObject id: String, someDao dao: SomeDao) {
        guard let object = dao.getObject(id: id) else {
            preconditionFailure("Object does not exist!")
        }

        self.object = object
        self.dao = dao
    }

    //MARK: - MVP. Both the onAttach and onDetach must assign the self.view property!

    func onAttach(view: View) {
        self.view = view
    }

    func onDetach(view: View) {
        self.view = nil
    }

    //MARK: - Public interface

    /// Sample public method that can be called from the view (e.g. a ViewController)
    /// that will load some data and tell the view to display them.
    func loadData() {
        guard let view = view else {
            return
        }

        let items = dao.getItem(forObject: object)
        view.showItems(items)
    }

    //MARK: - Private
}
```

Comment: Can you share the implementation of Presenter?

Comment: @mehdok I have added a sample presenter class.

Comment: Your view is like this ??
`protocol SampleView: MvpView {}`

Comment: @mehdok there is no base protocol for views, because of Swift's limitations in generic protocols. So the views are just protocols.

Comment: 0_o What is the purpose of receiving a `View` (`func onDetach(view: View)`)? It does not make sense to me.

Comment: @eMdOS it is a lifecycle method meaning that the view is detached i.e. not show on the screen. there you can stop sensors (accelerometer, gps, etc.), regular refresh of data, pause/clean-up open gl, etc. the detach should be probably called in `viewWillDisappear ` instead of `deinit` though. there could also be an `onDestroyView` method which can be called in the `deinit`. thus we could detach when pushing a screen over the current one.

Comment: @shelll That is not what I meant.
```swift
func onDetach(view: View) {
    self.view = nil
}
```
What does not make sense to me is, why you are receiving a `View` if you are not using it?. `func onDettach() { self.view = .none }` should be enough.

Comment: @eMdOS this is a basic example where there is nothing in the `onDetach`, except for the mandatory `self.view = nil`. the detach is a good place for e.g. pausing media playback and clean-up. but yes, the view in the parameter is the one that is currently in the `self.view` property...

Comment: @shelll how to do this base class if controller `TableViewController` not a `UIViewController `

Comment: @a.masri you need an "MVP" implementation per base `UIViewController` class (or any UIView, if you need that). They will look the same except they will inherit from different VC e.g. `class BaseMvpNavigationController<M, V, P: MvpPresenter>: UINavigationController` or `class BaseMvpTableViewController<M, V, P: MvpPresenter>: UITableViewController`. Implementations are the same.