# Specialized ViewConrtoller instantiation from storyobard

Tags: swift, generics, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a ViewModel specialized ViewController like this:

```
final class MyViewConrtoller<MyViewModel>: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: MyViewModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

I set the type of the ViewController in InterfaceBuilder.
Then I try to instantiate it as follow:

```
guard let myViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController<MyViewModel> else { return }
```

And it looks like the cast fails. An instance is indeed created (before the cast) but when it tries to cast it, a nil is returned.

Is there anything I'm missing?

**EDIT:**

Looking further I found an interesting solution which I am going to try out. Here is the link for those who might need it:

[Link Storyboard to UIViewController with Generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282965/link-storyboard-to-uiviewcontroller-with-generic)

Answer (score 1):

How about if you create a base class as below and use the subclass inside Storyboard.

```
class MyBaseViewController<MyViewModel> : UIViewController {
    var viewModel: MyViewModel?
}

final class MyViewConrtoller: MyBaseViewController<MyViewModel> {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Now use it like:

```
 private func LoadMyViewContrller() {
        guard let myViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewConrtoller else { return }

        myViewController.viewModel = yourViewModel
        myViewController.loadView()

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I kind of found the same solution using a dummy controller. I edited my post with the link.