# Using protocol with generic data type to pass data between screens

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, protocols

I am Android Developer that started learning iOS. I am trying to pass data between the master-detail style app.
I got `controller1` that has a list of `ToDo` items, and `controller2` that allows to create a new `ToDo` item and add it to the list on `controller1`.

I have created a protocol:

```
protocol ListDataHolder {
    
    associatedtype T
    
    func addItem(item: T)
    
    func reloadData()
}
```

Assigned `self` in `prepare` of `controller1`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let controller2 = segue.destination as? Controller2{
            controller2.toDoDataHolder = self
        }
    }
```

Declared delegate in `controller2`

```
// how do I tell to use ToDo class for generic type here
var toDoDataHolder: ListDataHolder? = nil
```

And use it like this:

```
@IBAction func onAddClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let toDo = ToDo()
        ...
        toDoDataHolder?.addItem(item: toDo)
        toDoDataHolder?.reloadData()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

I got a few errors when going this way:

For delegate declaration:

```
Protocol 'ListDataHolder' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

When using `addItem()` :

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ToDo' to expected argument type 'ListDataHolder.T'
Insert ' as! ListDataHolder.T'
Member 'addItem' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'ListDataHolder'; use a generic constraint instead
```

When I remove generic from protocol and just have `addItem(item: ToDo)`, everything works fine. But I want to be able to use `ListDataHolder` with any data type.

This is just experimentation for me, I am not looking for a correct way to pass data between controllers.

EDIT: you can find complete code in this GitHub repo: [github.com/Sermilion/ios_learning](http://github.com/Sermilion/ios_learning)

Comment: can you share small demo project via GitHub? I am a little confused in your description and cannot reproduce on my own

Comment: @Igor hey Igor, I created a public repo and pushed the code there: https://github.com/Sermilion/ios_learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to make the second view controller generic using the protocol *and* limit the type of objects being used (or held) by the class conforming to `ListDataHolder`

This can be done in the declaration of the view controller

```
class SecondViewController<Holder: ListDataHolder>: UIViewController where Holder.T == ToDo
```

then your method `onAddClicked` will work as is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the same error as with the answer from @Sandeep Bhandari ```Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f85fdc05550> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameTextField.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException```

Comment: It must have to do something to it. When I do not use generics in `ListDataHolder` everything works fine. I have a link to the repo in git in the question above, u can test it if you feel like it.

Comment: @joakim-danielson: Though the exception description is not appropriate, actual issue is with storyboard and viewcontroller with generics. if you remove the generics `<Holder: ListDataHolder>` from `SecondViewController` it will work fine. Thats what I mentioned in my answer as well. Storyboards are not designed to work with Generics, it tries to instantiate view controller without resolving the generics hence crashes

Comment: @Sermilion I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282965/link-storyboard-to-uiviewcontroller-with-generic) that might help with generic view controllers

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think it is fair to say your answer did answer the given question.  The problem with generics and ViewControllers are not related here. I ll accept your answer. Sandeep Bhandari thank you for your input as well. This was a great excercise for me and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using associated type in `ListDataHolder` protocol use `ToDo` if your are always passing `ToDo` instance to the `addItem` method.

If you want this protocol `addItem` method will work with any genericType use following code.

```
protocol ListDataHolder {
    func addItem<T:Decodable>(item: T)
    func reloadData()
}

struct ToDo: Decodable {

}

class A: ListDataHolder {
   
    func addItem<T:Decodable>(item: T) {
          print("Add Item called")
    }
    
    func reloadData(){

    }
}
```

Here you need to implement Delegation design pattern.
Please check Delegation design pattern in detail.

Comment: hey, thank you. I will read about delegation design pattern. Thanks for the hint.