# Swift Generics and Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, generics, storyboard, interface-builder

So I have a base class with generics that inherits from UIView

```
class TemplateView<T: ViewData.View>: UIView {
    ...
}
```

I have several subclasses of this for example:

```
class TemplateLabel: TemplateView<ViewData.View.Label> {
    ...
}
```

In Storyboard I have views with `Custom Class` set to the correct subclass of `TemplateView<T>` ex: `TemplateLabel` and it finds the source code when I press the arrow and the `Module` is also found, but auto fill does not find it.

I get the views with `Storyboard ID` and then take the `ViewController.view` property.

On build time everything works but on runtime I get exception:

> Unknown class _TtC7Project13TemplateLabel in Interface Builder file.

Why?

Comment: Hi, can not check it right now, but may be the reason is that subclass of generic class must also be a generic class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a generic class as a custom view in Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263882/use-a-generic-class-as-a-custom-view-in-interface-builder)