# Why can't interface builder use a concrete generic subclass of of UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance, interface-builder

First things first... this has been voted to close as a duplicate of why you can't use Generics directly in Interface Builder.  The TLDR answer there is IB uses Objective-C and Objective-C doesn't support generics.  That and there's no way to specify a generic's 'specialty' (i.e. what type it uses) anyway.  That's understood and makes complete sense.

This question however is about why you can't use a ***subclass of a fully-defined/specified generic***, which again, fully defines that generic's specialty so IB doesn't need to know anything about generics or even that a generic is being used in the first place.

Consider the following class...

```
class MyView : UIView
{
}
```

We can easily use this class in Interface Builder by dragging out a view, then changing its class type to be `MyView`.  When instantiated, `MyView`s init-with-coder is called as expected.

Now consider these classes...

```
class MyGenericView<T> : UIView
{
}

class MyView : MyGenericView<String>
{
}
```

In this case, even though `MyView` is based on the concrete type `MyGenericView<String>` which itself is based on `UIView`, you *can't* use this class in Interface Builder.  But why?  This is a fully-qualified class that is a subclass of `UIView`, but the application warns that it cannot find the specified class.

> Of note, and to clarify my question, it's my understanding that `MyView` here is *not* a Generic.  It's a fully-defined concrete type that can be instantiated directly from its class-name and is ultimately based on NSObject (via UIView) so it would seem it should be fully compatible with Objective-C/IB, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  I'm trying to understand *why* that is because it's my understanding that ***Generics are a compiler feature, not a runtime feature*** meaning they get compiled right down to non-generic objects, but I could be wrong.

So... is this a bug?  If not, can someone shed some light on exactly why this particular scenario doesn't work as expected, addressing the compiler/runtime observations I mentioned from a technical perspective?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a generic class as a custom view in Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263882/use-a-generic-class-as-a-custom-view-in-interface-builder)