# Unknown class in Interface Builder file Xcode 8.3.1 Swift 3.1 (Subclassing TableViewController with Generic Class)

Tags: swift, uitableview, generics, interface-builder, xcode8

I seemed to have found another situation that causes the famous "**Unknown class in Interface Builder file.**"

I tried fixing this problem using all the suggestions people posted in the plethora of other Q/A's regarding this bug and none of them worked.

I have stripped down the code as much as possible to isolate the problem. Here it is:

**Code that causes error:**

Class 1:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewControllerSubclass<T:Any>:UITableViewController{

}
```

Class 2:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewControllerSubclassChild:TableViewControllerSubclass<Int>{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Main StoryBoard has single UITableViewController that inherits from `TableViewControllerSubclassChild`. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

When I run the project as is I get the following output in the console:

```
2017-04-13 15:50:30.226 TableViewControllerBug[6087:165667] Unknown class _TtC22TableViewControllerBug32TableViewControllerSubclassChild in Interface Builder file.
```

and the breakpoint `viewDidLoad` is never hit.

Now if you remove the use of generics in both classes and run the project there is no output to the console and the breakpoint at `viewDidLoad` is hit.

**Code that does NOT cause error**

NewClass 1:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewControllerSubclass:UITableViewController{

}
```

NewClass 2:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewControllerSubclassChild:TableViewControllerSubclass{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Here is the project with the [code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwnRr9_QOUldZy1EbHNTbFZPdGc)

**My questions:**

1. Is this a bug with Xcode/Interface builder? Or does the problem stem from  illegal use of generics?
2. If this is illegal use of generics how does go about using generics properly in this situation?
3. If this is a bug, does anyone know of a work around?

Any insight into the problem will help! Thanks!

Comment: Hi I have the same issue did you figure out something ?

Comment: The problem is that objective-C does not support generics and UITableViewController is an objective-C object (inherits from NSObject). So this is essentially an illegal use of generics. You can use generics on any object that inherits from NSObject.

Comment: Yes thanks beenie, I've read that here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27608442/2046106 i put the link in case of someone needs it.

Comment: Yup that's exactly it.